# What does Specialization Training do?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

You can specialize yourself and your staff in "Engine", "Graphics", "Story" and so on. What does this do? Is it just a label to help you assign the right people to tasks, or does it give a productivity boost for that person working in that field? Seems a bit expensive for just a label. I searched but I could not find a real answer, only guessing.